# When checkbox is checked - show text in email

Tags: android, email, checkbox

I am creating a app whereby the user inputs data into a form and then hits the button, opens up a emailing app and sends it off to the email address put in.

I have 3 checkboxes, one that asks if the user wants a call back, one if they want an email back and one saying no thanks to both. My current java code is:

```
        public void submitTicket(View view){
    EditText formName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    String name = formName.getText().toString();

    EditText formPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    String phone = formPhone.getText().toString();

    EditText formAsset = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    String asset = formAsset.getText().toString();

    EditText formLocation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    String location = formLocation.getText().toString();

    EditText formIssue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etIssue);
    String issue = formIssue.getText().toString();

    CheckBox phoneCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbPhone);
    boolean phoneBack = phoneCheckBox.isChecked();

    CheckBox emailCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbPhone);
    boolean emailBack = emailCheckBox.isChecked();

    CheckBox noCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbPhone);
    boolean noThanks = noCheckBox.isChecked();

    String ticketMessage = ticketSummary(name, phone, asset, location, issue,
            phoneBack, emailBack, noThanks);
```

And then the method which calls all the above is:

```
private String ticketSummary(String name, String phone, String asset, String location, String issue, boolean phoneBack, boolean emailBack, boolean noThanks){
    String ticketMessage = getString(R.string.ticket_request_name, name);
    ticketMessage += "\n";
    ticketMessage += "\n" + getString(R.string.ticket_request_number, phone);
    ticketMessage += "\n";
    ticketMessage += "\n" + getString(R.string.ticket_request_asset, asset);
    ticketMessage += "\n";
    ticketMessage += "\n" + getString(R.string.ticket_request_location, location);
    ticketMessage += "\n";
    ticketMessage += "\n" + getString(R.string.ticket_request_issue, issue);
    ticketMessage += "\n";
```

On the last line, I want to get the data from the checkbox for example, if the call back box was ticked, in the email it should say "The user requests a call back". If both call and email are ticked then "The user requests a call or email back" and if the no thanks checkbox is ticked then "The user doesn't require an update when issue is resolved".

Answer (score 0):

> when you click email submit button then in submit button clicklistener you write code for sending email which is performed by some INTENT action .and send data using intent